# VBA Is language (possible) intefering with code

Tags: excel, vba, date

Im trying to very simply calculate the number of days between two dates, and i think that the inherent language settings og excel/windows is intefering with the code, so if anyone can clarify is this is in fact the case or find a solution i would be very grateful.

My could should be able to find the number of days between any two given dates in the same year, so for arguments sake i take
- The first of January 2015 &
- The Seventh of January 2015

When i write these dates in excel it formats them to

01/01-2015 & 07/01-2015
Because danish dates start with the day, then the month and year

i then grab them from a ComboBox into the VBA code

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


With wb.Sheets("Start").Shapes("from_dropdown")
    sd = DateValue(.ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.Value))
End With

With wb.Sheets("Start").Shapes("to_dropdown")
    ed = DateValue(.ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.Value))
End With
```

But when i try to calculate the days between them i get 150 days. The reason i believe that it's the language thing that interferes is that when i display "sd" and "ed" with MsgBox it is displayed as

01/01-2015 and 01/07-2015 IE not Danish standard.

Have anyone come across this problem before? and have a fix? or am i simply doing something else completely wrong.

Full code is:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sd As Date
Dim ed As Date
Dim numDays

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


With wb.Sheets("Start").Shapes("from_dropdown")
    sd = DateValue(.ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.Value))
End With

With wb.Sheets("Start").Shapes("to_dropdown")
    ed = DateValue(.ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.Value))
End With

numDays = DateDiff("d", sd, ed)

MsgBox sd
MsgBox ed
MsgBox numDays
```

And the value in excel to which the ComboBox's refer is

01/01/2015

02/01/2015

03/01/2015

04/01/2015

05/01/2015

06/01/2015

07/01/2015

08/01/2015

09/01/2015

10/01/2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its problem with function `DateValue`.
Using function `Format` results looks correct:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sd As Date
Dim ed As Date
Dim numDays

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

sd = DateValue("01/01/2015")
ed = DateValue("07/01/2015")

numDays = DateDiff("d", sd, ed) 'numDays = 181

sd = Format("01/01/2015", "dd/mm/yyyy")
ed = Format("07/01/2015", "dd/mm/yyyy")

numDays = DateDiff("d", sd, ed) 'numDays = 6
```

Edit: mistake in the date format

Comment: Thanks so much! that did it!, argh i was banging my head against the wall :P